# Python Selenium search for sibbling [object Text] that only have a text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, html-parsing

I want to get the text of an expression in xpath that only has text in its sibling
[html_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUNjG.png)

I'm trying this way but it gives me an error and I don't know how to select the text, since it doesn't have any tag

```
driver.find_element('xpath','//li[@class="icon-feature"]//i[@class="icon-stotal"]//following-sibling::text()').text
```

Error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//li[@class="icon-feature"]//i[@class="icon-stotal"]//following-sibling::text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

I want to have only " 121 m2 Total" with this.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_element` must return a webelement, and you cannot convert a text node into a webelement.

In general to get text not wrapped in any tags, you must get the text of the parent and remove from it the text of the children. In this case there is only one child so

```
child  = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon-stotal']")
parent = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon-stotal']/parent::li")
```

Then

```
>>> parent.text.replace(child.text,'')
' 121 m total'
```

Answer (score 0):

[`find_element()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71105759/7429447) returns a WebElement and it can't return a *Text Node*. So you can't use:

```
//xpath_expression/text()
```

Hence the error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector
```

---

### Solution

The text ***121 m2 Total*** is within a text node and a decesdent of `<i class="icon-stotal">`. So to extract the text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='icon-feature']/i[@class='icon-stotal']"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='icon-feature']/i[@class='icon-stotal']"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: So, how can I convert it from Text Node to WebElement?, i tried to put something like this:
'//li[@class="icon-feature"]//i[@class="icon-stotal"]//following-sibling::*' but 
it does not work

Comment: Did you happen to check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218375/7429447) published against your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75218136/7429447)?

Comment: This is the problem, **121 m2** Total is not the decesdent of <i class="icon-stotal"> is its sibling.
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4CPJ.png)