# Can't get element value using selenium when parsing SPA site

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Also, I can't get at all any of the attributes that I see on the object.

The `HTML`-code of the element I'm trying to get the value from:

```
<div data-bn-type="text" class="draggableHandle css-1nxx0n5">Target text</div>
```

My parser-code:

```
chromedriver = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=chromedriver)
browser.get(url)

elem = browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='draggableHandle')
print(elem) # value "<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9a2947e3e80269469c153808fbba18b6", element="77af1794-a2b0-4522-a261-f7211869e6c1")>"
print(elem.get_attribute('session')) # value "None"
print(elem.get_attribute('element')) # value "None"
print(elem.text) # null value
```

I didn't find an answer on Google. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

I will be grateful for any answer!

Comment: you could try with the whole name of the class "draggableHandle css-1nxx0n5", or use xpath

Comment: @AndresOspina Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to get by partial match because the part `css-1nxx0n5` is dynamic. It only has two values, but I don't want to make two requests, because this will slow down the script. By complete match it turns out to be found. Can you tell me how to set `xpath`?

Answer (score 0):

[***find_element()***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71105759/7429447) returns a [**webelement**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) which doesn't have the following attribute/property:

- *`session`*
- *`element`*

Hence, ***None*** is printed.

Given the HTML:

```
<div data-bn-type="text" class="draggableHandle css-1nxx0n5">Target text</div>
```

To print the text ***Target text*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CLASS_NAME* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "draggableHandle"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.draggableHandle"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'draggableHandle')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)